# changing the value of a text field as another is changed and the same but reversed causing an error

Tags: java, swing, events

I am making a simple Miles-Kilometers converter that updates automatically as you type. The problem is that is that an error is thrown somewhere. I believe that this is because as i change one of the fields it handles the event and changes the other field but since that also has an event handler for when it is changed it tries to change the other field itself and they keep firing events back and forth until something somewhere explodes. Any idea how I can fix this or is there a different problem completely ?

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Book extends JFrame{
    private JTextField jtfKilometers = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField jtfMiles = new JTextField(10);

    public Book(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 0));

        JPanel jlblPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0, 50, 5));
        jlblPanel.add(new JLabel("Kilometers"));
        jlblPanel.add(new JLabel("Miles"));
        add(jlblPanel, "West");

        JPanel jtfPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0, 5, 5));
        jtfPanel.add(jtfKilometers);
        jtfPanel.add(jtfMiles);
        add(jtfPanel, "Center");

        jtfKilometers.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(jtfKilometers.getText().equals("")){
                    jtfMiles.setText("");
                }else{
                    jtfMiles.setText(Double.parseDouble(jtfKilometers.getText()) * 0.621371 + "");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                insertUpdate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                insertUpdate(e);
            }
        });

        jtfMiles.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(jtfMiles.getText().equals("")){
                    jtfKilometers.setText("");
                }else{
                    jtfKilometers.setText(Double.parseDouble(jtfMiles.getText()) * 1.60934 + "");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                insertUpdate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                insertUpdate(e);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Book f = new Book();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to add additional guard on the focus of the text fields**, so that you will be modifying only the other text field, not recursively both of them.

```
jtfKilometers.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    if (jtfKilometers.hasFocus()) { // ADD THIS LINE
        if (jtfKilometers.getText().equals("")) {
            jtfMiles.setText("");
        } else {
            jtfMiles.setText(Double.parseDouble(jtfKilometers.getText()) * 0.621371 + "");
        }
    }
}
```

and similarly

```
jtfMiles.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (jtfMiles.hasFocus()) { // ADD THIS LINE
            if (jtfMiles.getText().equals("")) {
                jtfKilometers.setText("");
            } else {
                jtfKilometers.setText(Double.parseDouble(jtfMiles.getText()) * 1.60934 + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix for this is checking if the frame has focus when the event is triggered. This will prevent the event from triggering back and forth like is happening to you now.

See the adjusted code snippet from your sample below...

```
           public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            if(jtfMiles.hasFocus()){//Check for focus here....repeat same check on your other "insertUpdate" method for your other frame.
                if(jtfMiles.getText().equals("")){
                    jtfKilometers.setText("");
                }else{
                    jtfKilometers.setText(Double.parseDouble(jtfMiles.getText()) * 1.60934 + "");
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!